# How to access elements of a C++ map from a pointer?

Tags: c++

Simple question but difficult to formulate for a search engine: if I make a pointer to a map object, how do I access and set its elements? The following code does not work.

```
map<string, int> *myFruit;
myFruit["apple"] = 1;
myFruit["pear"] = 2;
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(*myFruit)["apple"] = 1;
```

or

```
myFruit->operator[]("apple") = 1;
```

or

```
map<string, int> &tFruit = *myFruit;
tFruit["apple"] = 1;
```

or (C++ 11)

```
myFruit->at("apple") = 1;
```

Comment: Don't forget to allocate the map object with new first.

Comment: My answers assume that `myFruit` is an already existing pointer to a `map<string, int>` somewhere, which may or may not have been allocated on the heap.

Comment: Depending no whether you want that additional semantics, C++11 offers a checked at() function that you can use as `ptr->at("apple")`

Answer (score 6):

`myFruit` is a pointer to a map. If you remove the asterisk, then you'll have a map and your syntax following will work.

Alternatively, you can use the dereferencing operator (`*`) to access the map using the pointer, but you'll have to create your map first:

```
map<string, int>* myFruit = new map<string, int>() ;
```

Comment: This kinda misses the point. He already knows that he cannot access the elements, but he has a pointer, and it's already allocated.

Comment: I re-read the question and I don't see a mention that the map is already allocated -- or did I miss this?

Answer (score 3):

```
map<string, int> *myFruit;
(*myFruit)["apple"] = 1;
(*myFruit)["pear"] = 2;
```

would work if you need to keep it as a pointer.