# Netbeans having some trouble with c++ std::map::operator[]

Tags: c++, netbeans, dictionary, operators

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0 and I'm having some trouble with it.

Here is a chunk of code explaining the problem :

```
typedef struct Context {
    bool finished;
    bool reliable;
    bool running;
    bool firstAckReceived;
    map<uint32_t, uint32_t>* missingChunks;
} Context;

map<uint32_t, Context*>* contexts;
...
this->contexts->operator[]((uint32_t) ctrl.getSource())->running = true;
```

When using suggestion (CTRL+Space), the operator[] returns a Context& as expected, but can't give me any suggestion after that. Netbeans doesn't that it's a Context which can be de-referenced to get Context fields.

Compilation is OK
Moreover, "-running" is highlighted as an error which keeps bothering me.
Does this happen a lot ?

Plus, I think I should be able to access the element using a syntax as follows, but g++ complains ...

```
this->contexts[(uint32_t) ctrl.getSource()]->running = true;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On a side note, why all the stars? How are you planning on deleting all these raw pointers?

Comment: I made a mistake and posted the comment before finishing it ... Just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have

```
this->contexts->operator[]((uint32_t) ctrl.getSource())->running = true;
//            ^------------- notice this
```

rather than

```
this->contexts.operator[]((uint32_t) ctrl.getSource())->running = true;
//            ^------------- notice this
```

Recall we use `->` for pointers and `.` for non-pointers.

The following

```
this->contexts[(uint32_t) ctrl.getSource()]->running = true;
```

is equivalent to the second version. You either need to dereference the pointer, or, my preferred way, consider why you have so many raw pointers going on.

I suggest you change

```
map<uint32_t, Context*>* contexts;
```

to

```
map<uint32_t, Context*> contexts;
```

And then you should consider who owns the raw `Context` pointers in the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Yes too many pointers were used for absolutely no reason ...
I removed 2 ou of 3 and it works like a charm.
Thanks again !

Comment: @SOKS glad that fixed it - you could use the pointers - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236485/how-to-access-elements-of-a-c-map-from-a-pointer - bit I suspect you'll get a memory leak if you do